# char * gives garbage value when pointing to a variable of a function in C

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, pointer-to-pointer

When i pass a pointer to a function and then change the pointer to a another location of the memory, I get SIGSEV or garbage values. Where is a code to demonstrate that:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void fn(char *n) {
  /*
   * imagine this variable 'b' is
   * a part of a structure of
   * some library
   */
  char *b = "hello, world!";

  n = b;
}

int main() {
  char *a = NULL;
  fn(a);

  /* it throws garbage or SIGSEV */
  printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

I know what's the reason for this problem. The function `fn`, when called creates a variable `b` but when `fn` ends, `b` is deleted. And therefore, `a` is pointing to a memory that the program doesn't own. What do I do to fix this program. I know, I can solve the issue just by using C++ with it's std::string. But I have to do it in C.
Thanks.

Comment: Nothing you do to `n` in `fn()` changes what `a` in `main()` points to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that you need to pass the pointer `a` defined in `main` to the function `fn` by reference. In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. Thus dereferencing the passed pointer the function will have a direct access to the object pointed to by the pointer and can change it.

```
void fn(char **n) {
  /*
   * imagine this variable 'b' is
   * a part of a structure of
   * some library
   */
  char *b = "hello, world!";

  *n = b;
}
```

And in main you need to write

```
fn( &a );
```

Pay attention to that the pointer `a` will be valid after the function call because it points to a string literal used in `fn` and string literals have static storage duration.

Answer (score 1):

You want to modify `n` value itself, not the data pointed by it.

So

- `fn` prototype should be `void fn(char ** n)`
- the assignment should be `*n = b` or better  `n* = strddup (...);`
- the call sholud be `fn(&a);`

Answer (score 1):

Your function isn't updating `a` to point to the string; in your `main` function `a` is still `NULL` after the call to `fn`.

Remember that C passes all function arguments by value; when you call `fn` the argument `a` is evaluated and the result of that evaluation (`NULL`) is *copied* to the formal argument `n`.  `a` and `n` are completely different objects in memory and changes to one are not reflected in the other.

In order for `fn` to write a new value to `a` you must pass a *pointer* to `a`:

```
void fn( char **n )
{
  *n = "hello, world"; // no need for a separate variable
}

int main( void )
{
  ...
  fn( &a );
  ...
}
```

Alternately, you can have `fn` return the new pointer value and assign it to `a`:

```
char *fn( void )
{
  return "hello, world";
}

int main( void )
{
  char *a = fn();
  ...
}
```

although this only works if you return a pointer to a string literal, static variable, or the result of a function that returns a pointer like `malloc` or `fopen` or something like that; you can't return a pointer to a local variable like

```
char *fn( void )
{
  char buf[] = "hello, world";
  return buf;
}
```

because the local variable `buf` *ceases to exist* once the function returns and that pointer value is now *invalid*.

General rule:

```
void update( T *ptr ) // for any non-array type T
{
  *ptr = new_T_value(); // writes a new value to the thing
}                       // ptr points to

int main( void )
{
  T var;
  update( &var ); // write a new value to var
  ...
}
```

If we replace `T` with a pointer type `P *`, we get

```
void update( P **ptr )
{
  *ptr = new_Pstar_value(); 

int main( void )
{
  P *var;
  update( &var ); 
  ...
}
```

The semantics are exactly the same; `ptr` still has an extra layer of indirection, we still use `&var` as the argument, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way is to malloc `a` in `main` function and pass it to the `fn` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fn(char *n) {
  /*
   * imagine this variable 'b' is
   * a part of a structure of
   * some library
   */
    
   char *b = "Hello, world";
   memcpy(n, b, strlen(b));

}

int main() {
  char *a = malloc(100);   // 100 is a sample
  fn(a);

  /* it throws garbage or SIGSEV */
  printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

Also, you can avoid memcpy, by assigning the struture variable to n, instead of b

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior.:) You need to write at least memcpy(n, b, strlen(b) + 1); instead of memcpy(n, b, strlen(b));. But in any case the approach is not good because it is unclear why there is used the magic number 100.:)

Comment: You used malloc() but forgot to free().

Comment: 1- I know, 100 is sample and it depends on the length of mentioned structure variable length.  2- Yes it is correct, It is necessary to free allocated memory in correct point.